# Available control system from .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

I want to have parking available system. So I have boolean variable which is `Status`. And I set default variable is true. It means parking slot is available.

After added data `Status` is false. But it doesn't work. It still save same data. How can I have control system for available or not?

This is my model

```
 public Boolean Status { get; set; } = true;
```

This is my if else control

```
  if (obj.Status == true)
  {
      _db.Bookings.Add(obj);
      obj.Status = false;
      _db.SaveChanges();

      TempData["success"] = "Booking created successfully";
  }
  else
  {
      TempData["error"] = "This slot is already booked for " + obj.PickHours + " hours";
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View(obj);
```

Comment: You are setting it to false after inserting it.  You need to update that db object.

Comment: C# is pass by value for methods unless when using the `ref` keyword (which is not valid for `.Add()`), meaning `_db.Bookings.Add(obj);` is going to add a copy of obj to the list *not* a reference to it. Hence, `obj.Status = false;` will only mutate the obj, and not the copy of obj that exists in the collection. All you have to do is swap those two lines, so the obj would have been mutated prior to the add, and the proper copy will be added to the collection